# Stop div from sliding up when it's textbox is focused on

Tags: css, z-index, jquery

I'm trying to make the upper panel of my application to have `top` property to be `-80px` by default so it's invisible except of a small part of it. And when the user hover with his mouse on that part, it slides down again.

The problem is, this div has a `textbox`, i want the div to stop sliding up when the user is typing on this `textbox` even if he move his mouse pointer away, but unfortunately don't know how to do this, here's my code :

**index.html**

```
<div id="taskInput">
    <div id="controllers">
         <input type="text" name="mainTask" id="mainTask">
         <button id="addMain">Add</button>
         <button id="resetMain">Reset</button>
    </div>       
</div>
```

**css of this part :**

```
#taskInput {
    background: red;
    width:606px;
    height:43px;    
    padding: 22px;    
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px -3px black;
    position: absolute;    
    z-index : 0;
    top:0px;
}
```

**script.js**

```
$(function(){
    $("#taskInput").delay(400).animate({top:-80}, 500,function(){});
    $("#taskInput").mouseover(
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({top:0}, 200, function(){});            
        });

    $("#taskInput").mouseout(function(evt){                    
        $(this).stop().animate({top:-80}, 200, function(){});           
    })

    $("#mainTask").focus(function(){
        //i though i can put something here to stop mouseout event or something
    })
})
```

Comment: You could unbind the `mouseout` event handler using `.off('mouseout')` (or `.unbind('mouseout')` for earlier versions of jQuery), then rebind it again on the `blur` event of the text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed my mind from my comment, there's no need to unbind the events or use a global variable to track it. You can use `document.activeElement` to get the currently focused element on the page, and compare its id to the id of your `<input>`, like so:

```
$("#taskInput").mouseout(function(evt){
    if(document.activeElement.id !== 'mainTask') {   
        $(this).stop().animate({top:-80}, 200, function(){});
    }            
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct3Tz/)

Comment: Ya i was looking for something like this. But is there .activeElement alternative in jQuery ? I feel like using DOM properties inside jQuery isn't that nice thing to do ?

Comment: @Rafael Your feeling makes absolutely no sense. You should use DOM properties as much as possible, even in jQuery code, because it's considerably faster.

Answer (score 1):

add a flag to the animate to top and change it in the focus function

i have not tested this but it should work

```
$(function(){
  writing = false;
  $("#taskInput").delay(400).animate({top:-80}, 500,function(){});
  $("#taskInput").mouseover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({top:0}, 200, function(){});            
    });

  $("#taskInput").mouseout(function(evt){   
    if(writing == false){                 
       $(this).stop().animate({top:-80}, 200, function(){});           
    }
  })

  $("#mainTask").focus(function(){
    //i though i can put something here to stop mouseout event or something
    writing = true
  })

  $("#mainTask").focusout(function(){
    //i though i can put something here to stop mouseout event or something
    writing = false
  })

})
```

Answer (score 1):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hu9pc/1/)

Easiest way is to give the #mainTask a `data-focus` attribute set to true, then when doing the `mouseout` on #taskInput, make sure it is False before animating the slideUp.

```
$(function(){
    // ... code

    $("#taskInput").mouseout(function(evt){      
        console.log($('#mainTask').data('focus'));            
        if ($('#mainTask').data('focus') === false) {        
            $(this).stop().animate({top:-80}, 200, function(){});
        }            
    })

    $("#mainTask").on({
        focus: function(){
            $(this).data('focus', true);
        },  
        blur: function () {
            $(this).data('focus', false);
        }
    });
})
```

​

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you could also give this a try:

```
$('#taskInput').delay(400).animate({top:-80},500);

$('#taskInput').mouseover(function()
{
    $(this).stop().animate({top:0},200);            
});

$('#taskInput').mouseout(function()
{
    if(!$('#mainTask').is(':focus'))
    {
        $(this).stop().animate({top:-80},200);           
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eS5Fy/)**

### Edit:

You could also add this to your code:

```
$('#mainTask').blur(function()
{
    $('#taskInput').stop().animate({top:-80},200);
});
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/eS5Fy/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

in the $("#mainTask").focus event handler you can set a global boolean variable to true, set it to false in an blur event handler and check on the value of that variable in the #taskInput mouseout event handler

```
var preventSlide = false;

$("#taskInput").mouseout(function(evt){                    
    if (!preventSlide) {
        $(this).stop().animate({top:-80}, 200, function(){});           
    }
})

$("#mainTask").focus(function(){
    preventSlide = true;
})

$("#mainTask").blur(function(){
    preventSlide = false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var flag=true;

    $("#taskInput").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        if (flag) $(this).stop().animate({top: e.type=='mouseenter'?0:-80}, 200);
    }).delay(400).animate({top:-80}, 500);

    $("#mainTask").on('blur focus', function(e) {
        flag=e.type=='blur';
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XyVfn/4/)